# TeXShop print problem

Tags: texshop, printing, macos

I'm running TeXShop on a mac. Using as simplest as possible code of,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
A very simple text!
\end{document}
```

the printing output is exactly the same as the code (with all the tags and without the page number), while it usually will be only the body text. All the TeX settings are default, TeXShop ver 4.62 and TeX Live Utility ver  1.49 have been installed without any error.

Any idea for print correction would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How to correct the print output of the texshop? I would like to have only "A very simple text!" in the pdf output, while I get \documentclass{article}....\end{document}

Comment: what are you doing to print? you can print the tex source of course (which sounds like what you are doing) but otherwise you normally run latex to generate pdf then print that?

Comment: This is the exact issue. Normal print of the latex (TeXShop in Mac) prints the code instead of content.

Comment: I don't have texshop but if you select print from the editor I'd expect it to print the source code, have you run latex to generate a pdf?

Comment: Thanks, I need to google it

Comment: looking at the texshop documentation at https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/index.html (just the first screenshot) it looks like you want to press **typeset** then use the printer icon from the pdf preview window

Comment: First, TeXShop doesn’t print the Source by default. Second, do you see a window with the final typeset document? If not, you must typeset the Source before printing.

Comment: Thanks, guys. But it was not the case, I think IDE (TeXShop) does not work properly because in TEXMAKER (https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) everything works correctly again.